# I want to make drag and drop using konva library

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs

I want to make drag and drop using konva library but main thing is that I want fixed part for drag if I upload image with big size then extra size will hide and image show only as visible part[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb50I.jpg)

I want that If i upload the image that will fit into this frame and I can drag and drop or do resize inside only that part if uploaded image is grater then that part then extra part will hide.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you were trying to do...some pics or fiddles can be helpful...